# Cesium: Failed to obtain image tile X : 0 Y : 0 Level : 0

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wms, 3d, cesium

I'm trying to make a Cesium-based 3D web-viewer. At the moment I'm stuck with an error. Let me describe the situation:

I have a PostGIS database, containing the 3D geometry of a building (which I extracted from my main database, containing many more building geometries).

I have entered this database into Geoserver 2.7.2.

I wrote a simple Cesium script calling the WMS which is serving the database.

> Error: error occurred in "v": Failed to obtain image tile X : 0 Y : 0
>   Level : 0.

Now, I read some things on this error, something about missing top level tiles. But all this internet literature seems to be about terrains, but that is not what I am doing.

Is there someone who can explain me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Cesium shows a base imagery layer, typically Bing aerial images.  The very first one it tries to load is `image tile X : 0 Y : 0 Level : 0` as mentioned in your error message.  So, your error message is about the base imagery, not your 3D model.

So this error implies the base imagery is not accessible for some reason, perhaps an expired Bing key or maybe there's no connection to the public Internet, or Bing is not selected as the base layer and the current selection is inaccessible.  The solution could be one of: (a) try a [different Bing key](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/), or (b) try a different initial base imagery layer, like so:

```
var imagerySources = Cesium.createDefaultImageryProviderViewModels();
var selectedIndex = imagerySources.length - 1;

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    imageryProviderViewModels : imagerySources,
    selectedImageryProviderViewModel : imagerySources[selectedIndex]
});
```